# CRTP function specialisation: add to the docstring of the interface function

Tags: doxygen

I am implementating classes derived by CRTP. This calls for a function specialisation where needed. Now, for a specific specialisation in the derived class, I would like to add something to the docstring of the 'global' interface function. How can I do that (with doxygen 1.9.1)?

### Example

Consider this example:

```cpp
template <class D>
class CommonInterface
{
public:
    /**
    \brief My common function description.
    */
    void foo()
    {
        static_cast<D*>(this)->foo_impl();
    }
};

class A : public CommonInterface<A>
{
public:
    A() = default;

private:
    void foo_impl() {};

    friend class CommonInterface<A>;
};
```

`A::foo()` gets shown at the documentation of `A` as the derived method of `CommonInterface<D>::foo`. Now, I want to add some documentation for the method `foo` that is only visible in the documentation of `class A` but not in the documentation of `class CommonInterface`.

I don't want to:

- Override the function, rather I use CRTP specifically to avoid the override because I use templated 'overrides'.
- Document `foo_impl()` as it  would make no sense in the public documentation.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add some documentation for the method foo that is only visible in the documentation of class A but not in the documenttaion of class CommonInterface?

Comment: @albert Yes that is exactly what I mean! I've edited based on your formulation, that was much better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but more a workaround?

I don't think that there exist something for this in doxygen, but maybe the following might be an acceptable workaround?

**Doxyfile**

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
QUIET                  = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
PREDEFINED             = DOXYGEN
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
```

**aa.h**

```
template <class D>
class CommonInterface
{
public:
    /**
    \brief My common function description.
    \details My common function detailed description.
    */
#if DOXYGEN
virtual
#endif
    void foo()
    {
        static_cast<D*>(this)->foo_impl();
    }
};

class A : public CommonInterface<A>
{
public:
    A() = default;

#if DOXYGEN
/**
\copydoc CommonInterface::foo

Some extra documentation for A::foo ?
*/
    void foo()
    {
        static_cast<D*>(this)->foo_impl();
    }
#endif
private:
    void foo_impl() {};

    friend class CommonInterface<A>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the work around. Indeed that would do the trick, though aesthetically is not amazing to have source code just for docs. A function in doxygen to fake a function definition would in that respect look nicer. But I guess that it might go against some things in doxygen

Comment: This is indeed a bit of a dirty / not aesthetically amazing trick. I think this "curiously recurring template pattern" is a very special case (I never saw it before). I don't see quickly a real possibility to implement something specific for a, non virtual, function in a derived class (as this is what is happening here in my opinion). Maybe worth an enhancement issue in the doxygen github issue tracker (though I'm not optimistic about the chances for a fix).

Comment: Will do! (CRTP is indeed curious, what's in the name, but I needed it to template `override` function)

Comment: Oops I wrote "I never saw it before" but I see now that doxygen uses it in its own code as well (e.g. in docparser.h: `class DocRoot : public CompAccept<DocRoot>`) must have gone in my bit-bucket